# Store each character from a std::string into a std::string

Tags: c++, string, std, stdstring

I would like to know what method you would use to get each character from a std::string and store it in another std::string.

I find the problem when the std::string has special characters, such as "á". If I do:

```
std::string test = "márcos";

std::string char1 = std::string(1, test.at(0));
std::string char2 = std::string(1, test.at(1));
std::string char3 = std::string(1, test.at(2));
std::string char4 = std::string(1, test.at(3));

std::cout << "Result: " << char1 << " -- " << char2 << " -- " << char3  << " -- " << char4 << std::endl;
```

Output: Result: m -- � -- � -- r

As you can see, the desired result would be: "m - á - r - c" but this is not the case because the special character is stored as two characters.

How can we solve this? thanks :)

Comment: That probably because your editor saved the source file (including the literal string) in UTF-8. Some characters (like the international characters) are stored as multiple bytes and each byte will be added to the string `test`. You can easily check this by doing `std::cout << test.length() << '\n';`. It will most likely be more than `6`.

Comment: That's true, if I do test.length() the result is 7. But I'm searching a way to store each character of the string, including if it has UTF-8 characters in another string. Character by character ^^

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wide characters may not solve the issue because 1) there are characters outside the BMP which wchar_t may not cover and 2) there are characters that require multiple code points to store, for example the letters in complex scripts (Arabic, Indic...) or emojis that are represented by a series of characters linked together by [ZWNJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner)

Comment: @phuclv Yeah it wasn't a good idea. And if the editor saves the file in UTF-8 then it doesn't really matter anyway (it will still be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bytes ([between one and four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding)) used to encode a codepoint in UTF-8 can be determined by looking at the high bits of the leading byte.

```
bytes    codepoints             byte 1    byte 2    byte 3    byte 4
  1      U+0000  .. U+007F      0xxxxxxx        
  2      U+0080  .. U+07FF      110xxxxx  10xxxxxx        
  3      U+0800  .. U+FFFF      1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx        
  4      U+10000 .. U+10FFFF    11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

The following breaks a UTF-8 encoded `std::string` into the individual characters.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int bytelen(char c)
{
    if(!c)                  return 0;   // empty string
    if(!(c & 0x80))         return 1;   // ascii char       ($)
    if((c & 0xE0) == 0xC0)  return 2;   // 2-byte codepoint (¢)
    if((c & 0xF0) == 0xE0)  return 3;   // 3-byte codepoint (€)
    if((c & 0xF8) == 0xF0)  return 4;   // 4-byte codepoint ()

    return -1;                          // error
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "$¢€";
    std::cout << "'" << test << "' length = " << test.length() << std::endl;

    for(int off = 0, len; off < test.length(); off += len)
    {
        len = bytelen(test[off]);
        if(len < 0) return 1;

        std::string chr = test.substr(off, len);
        std::cout << "'" << chr << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/19vhqP):

```
'$¢€' length = 10
'$'
'¢'
'€'
''
```